# Dynamically selecting a table in a query based on result from joined SELECT

Tags: mysql, join, table, variable

I have seen many examples but they don't match with my special case (I know... everyone's case is a special case :D )

I have to match values from different tables, some of which are named after the id field of the main table (whenever a new customer is added, a "Bill_xxx" table is created). For example:

```
table: Customers
--------------------------------
custId   | name       | status
--------------------------------
34       | CustomerA  | Active
35       | CustomerB  | Inactive
36       | CustomerC  | Active
--------------------------------


table: Bill_34
--------------------
id   | InvoiceNumber
--------------------
001  | 98767575
002  | 98767576
--------------------


table: Bill_35
--------------------
id   | InvoiceNumber
--------------------
001  | 36528
002  | 36529
--------------------


table: Bill_36
--------------------
id   | InvoiceNumber
--------------------
001  | 485795
002  | 485796
--------------------
```

Basically I'm trying to find a way to build a query like this, just to run it on demand via SQLYog. (I know I can use a cursor, but I need to run this in a prod db, for which I don't have permissions to create Stored Procedures):

```
Select * from 
(Select custId from Customer where status = 'Active') as customers
INNER JOIN
(Select * from Bill_[custId]) as bills
```

If it's not clear, I need to dynamically build the name of the table in the second query based on the id's I get from the first one

And expect to receive something like this

```
--------------------------------------------
custId  |  id  | InvoiceNumber
--------------------------------------------
34      | 001  | 98767575
34      | 002  | 98767576
35      | 001  | 36528
35      | 002  | 36529
36      | 001  | 485795
36      | 002  | 485796
____________________________________________
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: You should fix your table design as soon as possible. This seems like dynamic unions . See [How do I perform a UNION query on a dynamic list of tables?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22945/how-do-i-perform-a-union-query-on-a-dynamic-list-of-tables) or [mysql - create dynamic union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49923079/mysql-create-dynamic-union)

Comment: MySQL does not support computing a table name in SQL.  Instead, do it in your app.  Better yet, do not have lots of 'identical' tables.